# How to call fields individually like this in Twig template?

Tags: theming, 8, nodes

I'm familiar with the Drupal 8 theming API,as well as all of the theme template suggestions available when Twig debug is enabled. I have created content type named (machine name) events .For overriding node.html.twig I have made node--events.html.twig . In this (node--events.html.twig) file I am trying to get individual values like below:
{{content.body}} 
But it returns null . I have also tried {{ node.field_machine_name.value }} but It is not working for all the fields .

Comment: If {{ content.body }} not works, then this field is not in the display mode. If .value on a node field doesn't work, the field has no value property. See https://www.md-systems.ch/de/blog/techblog/2017/02/20/twig-and-entity-field-api-or-how-to-take-control-of-nodehtmltwig

Comment: The field is in the display mode .

Comment: If typing `{{ content.field_machine_name }}` does not work in a basic node template, something else is wrong and there is not enough information here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my node twig template file I have this which works for me:

```
{{ content.field_name|field_label }}
{{ content.field_name|field_value }}
```

This works if the [twig_field_value](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_field_value) module is enabled.

Comment: You'll need to enable this module [twig_field_value](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_field_value) if you want field_label and field_value filter to work.

Comment: I have tried but no luck

Comment: Good point, twig_field_value must be enabled - I forgot about that. Try using {{ dump(content) }} to see what fields are available in the content object. If it's not working it could be a config problem?

Comment: `{{ dump(content) }}` renders nothing at all and a white page is returned…

Comment: sounds like content is undefined in your case. Do you have display php errors enabled?